# how generate image continuously around textview in android

Tags: android, textview, border

I want to keep the custom border for a textview with an image, such that image is repeated all around the border. And the textview is generated dynamically. so the image must also generate dynamically around the textview.

Can any one help?..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got your point. you want to put border to TextView.

textview_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#202d5c88"/>    

<stroke android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"
        />

<!-- <padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         />  -->

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```

save this xml in drawable folder.

set this xml as background to textview and give quick reply on this i.e is it useful or not ?

Comment: i dont want an image as a background but i want as a border. i.e a small image which is repeated along the border just like a frame.

Comment: i have checked the above code but it is repeating the image as a background. I have even tried by using drawableTop,drawableBotton and other two drawables but it is showing only one image per side its not repeating

Comment: Is there any other options.

Comment: I know that but I want to have a custom frame like border for my textview